# Why some iPhone app not in Notification Center but still got the Notification of the app,

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, apple-push-notifications

I disable some iOS app notification feature, I move it to 'Not in Notification Center' of 'Settings' but sometime, it still can send notification to my iPhone, eg, Facebook, I am strange with this case, How does it implemented this feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse "in the notification center" with "push notifications enabled." I can remove an app from the notification center but still have it receiving push notifications in the form of badge numbers.

There is an "include" and a "do not include" section in [Notification Center](http://9to5mac.com/2013/10/10/ios-7-how-to-customize-and-use-notification-center/).

Tap "edit" at top right corner of the Notification Center. This allows you to drag apps around in the Notification Center.

Hold the app you want to stop push notifications from, by the lines on the right hand side to its name, and drag it into "do not include" section. It will automatically close all banner settings for the app, and voila! You are good to go.

Comment: I want stop 'notification' from the app, how to do it ? thanks

Comment: drag your App into "do not include" section. It will automatically close all banner settings for the app and you can also off your app badge count there too hope it helps you.

Comment: no... although I move to 'not include' but still appear, only way can disable it, set it 'No Alert' in detail view of the app .